# Why would I include a Func/Func<T> as a parameter?

Tags: c#, .net

I acknowledge that they can be useful, but I'm trying to wrap my head around when I would actually want to have a func as a parameter of a method.

```
public void WeirdMethod(int myNumber, func op);
```

In terms of design and functionality, could someone explain to me some circumstances where I would want to consider this? Theories of "reusability" isn't going going to help me much. Real world scenarios would be best. Help me think like you lol.

Here's about all I know:

- This would allow me to pass a delegate
- This would allow me to use a lambda expression.

Yeap...

NOTE:
I know this thread will get closed since there's no "right" answer. But I think what clicked it for me just now was "delayed calculation".

Comment: some of the answers given here might make more sense if you read this introductory item on map-reduce / functional programming first: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/08/01.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A general scenario is when you must pass a delayed calculation to your method. This is useful when calculating something is expensive, for example, when you cache something.

```
public Guid GetFromCache(string key, Func<Guid> make) {
    Guid res;
    if (!cache.TryGetValue(key, out res)) {
        res = make();
        cache.Add(key, res);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Now you can call this method as follows:

```
Guid guid = GetFromCache(myKey, () => database.MakeNewGuid());
```

Comment: Thank you for including the lambda. Sometimes just seeing it following a conceptual explanation is all it takes.

Answer (score 4):

- Deferring operations until a later time. A very practical example is deferring change tracking until an object tree is fully populated. Each type or repository can tell you what it wants done, and the caller can decide when to actually do it.
- Composition of logic (as Justin Niessner mentioned).
- Abstraction, e.g. ("here's a contract that has inputs and ouputs, but I don't care what it's implementation is as long as it fulfills the contract). For example, you could pass a "statusWriter" `Func` to a method which might write to a console, debug window, log file, database, or do nothing at all. All the consuming method knows is that it consumes a type and invokes it when desired.
- Along the same lines, passing a `Func` to a method allows an abstracted and simple way of allowing a *where* predicate to be defined by the caller. I use this paradigm frequently to support a strongly-typed filter to be applied to a result (not talking about LINQ to SQL, just filtering a list of information as the caller sees fit).
- Elegant functional paradigms, such as [this example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c.aspx) which demonstrates recursion using anonymous functions. These constructs would be verbose/impossible without the ability to pass one function to another (especially in an abbreviated form).

Comment: I completely forgot to think of functions as being semantically equivalent to their return values.

Answer (score 3):

If you had something asynchronous and you wanted to give it a callback method?

Answer (score 0):

They enable to you to Curry functions as well as use Functional Composition.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment? The ability to pass and return functions as values to/from functions is key in both situations. Delegates give you that mechanism in C#.

Comment: I was not the downvoter, but I did not upvote because I feel someone who does not understand `Func` would also likely not understand what `Curry` means is or how to do `Functional Composition`.

Comment: I'm with Scott; didn't (and won't) downvote, but I doubt that this answer--while correct--would be of much use to the assumed audience for this question.

Answer (score 0):

While you've almost certainly used delegates before (since that's what events are), LINQ is a prime example for when passing a delegate as a function parameter is useful.

Think about `Where`. You're supplying a piece of logic (specifically a definition of what meets your criteria--whatever they are) to a function that uses it as part of its execution.

Comment: I wasn't trying to identify an instance of using a func. I'm trying to understand their purpose so that I can start using them in my implementation code.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic: Do you understand why they're used in LINQ?

Comment: Yes, and I use them frequently.

Comment: If you understand why they're used there, then what are you asking? You said "I'm trying to wrap my head around when I would actually want to have a func as a parameter of a method."

Comment: "wrap my head around when I would actually want to *have a func as a *parameter* of a method*. Not "wrap my head around *where I would encounter one as an argument*". I was looking to understand when I would use them in my own implementations.